# Supernova Not generating the proper design of adobe XD file in trail version for Android XML?

Tags: xml, android-layout

Supernova Not generating the proper design of adobe XD file in trail version ? its due to trail version or its supernova issue Even the Supernova doesn't generating the accurate design .The design only contain the TextView and and styles? So Can we create the proper UI design Component in Supernova thats create android control and same design.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the supported layout components? Maybe you are using unsupported ones.

https://help.supernova.io/docs/importing-from-adobe-xd